# PDF form filled out with PyPDF2 is shown inconsistently in different PDF viewers

Tags: python, pdf, pdf-generation, pypdf

Here is a simple very easily reproducible example of the bug I am having in PyPDF2. Please help me figure out what is going on.

I want to generate this pdf:

[image]

As you can see, I have generated it so the code is working correctly. However, it looks like this only when viewed in mac viewer or safari. When I view THE SAME FILE in google chrome or brave or adobe I see this:

[image]

So page 2 just shows page 1 again. If I do n pages then all n pages are identical and they all say "page 1".

I put all the versions of the software I am using in the comments below. I want this to be viewable correctly in chrome, brave, adobe, and it's probably wrong in many others as well.

```
#find original pdf page here and save it in "path": https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/f8949.pdf
from PyPDF2 import PdfReader, PdfWriter  #, PdfFileMerger, PdfFileWriter, PdfFileReader
writer = PdfWriter()

reader = PdfReader(path)
page = reader.pages[0]
writer.add_page(page)
writer.update_page_form_field_values(writer.pages[0], {"f1_3[0]":"page1"})

reader = PdfReader(path)
page = reader.pages[0]
writer.add_page(page)
writer.update_page_form_field_values(writer.pages[1], {"f1_3[0]":"page2"})

with open("output.pdf", "wb") as output_stream:
        writer.write(output_stream)
        output_stream.close()


#PyPDF2==2.11.2
#PyPDF4==1.27.0
#Python 3.9.7
#Mac 12.1
#Brave 1.45.127
#Adobe 2022.003.20258


#safari good
#preview good

#google bad
#adobe bad
#brave bad
```

Comment: If i understand your code correctly, you have a text field widget for the same field `f1_3[0]` on each page and want to fill them with different values. That has to fail - all widgets for `f1_3[0]` represent the same abstract field and, therefore, share the same value. Some viewers may not correctly display this, though.

Comment: I thought the first input variable "writer.pages[i]" would make them different but I'm not sure. Is there a way to change the keys "f1_3[0]?" I know that when I use a pdf that has 2 different underlying pages the keys are "f1..." in the first page and then "f2..." in the second page. Would be great if I could change the keys to look like that.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is a bug in PyPDF2. We have issues with filling out forms for a long time, see https://github.com/py-pdf/PyPDF2/issues/355

Comment: It is filling out the form though. The result is correct when I view it in some pdf viewers. It's just that other pdf viewers are showing it incorrectly. Maybe it's a bug in the pdf viewers?

Comment: I'm not sure about that, but it's an issue PyPDF2 should be able to deal with. In any way, I doubt that this question will receive a better answer (as a side note : I'm the maintainer of PyPDF2)

Comment: FYI I just tried the exact same thing in 'pdfrw' a similar python pdf package. I got the exact same bug again. Furthermore, if I output two pdfs in this way from PyPDF2 lets say out1.pdf and out2.pdf then I cannot combine them. So -- out1.pdf says page1 on it if I open in mac viewer and out2.pdf says page2 if I open in mac viewer. When I combine them manually on mac viewer the resulting 2 pages both say page 1. If I combine them using pdfunite command its the same thing. If I combine them with PyPDF2 python code again the same thing.

Comment: Do you have any advice on how to simply write different things on multiple copies of the same input pdf in python and combine them? I have tried about 10 things and they have all failed on either Mac or Linux somehow.

Comment: Oh, interesting. Could you leave a comment what you have tried? That is an indicator that it might actually be an issuer of the viewers

Comment: But sadly I cannot tell you a solution that works

Comment: PyMuPDF (fitz) is typically pretty good. I just don't know if they support forms at all

Comment: I tried with pdfrw. I tried forming all the pages first and then writing to them after. I tried in linux with pdftk, ghostscript, pdfunite. I also tried PyMuPDF. In every single case I got the correct pdf I want when I view with mac viewer or safari but every single time it was wrong with google chrome.

Comment: The problem is that I am using the same original pdf and writing on copies of it. If I try with 2 different pdfs then there is no problem. I even tried make a duplicate of the pdf I need and changing the name and reading in the "same" file as two different paths. Still doesn't work.

Comment: When google chrome sees multiple pages with the same underlying pdf it just gives all the same pages with whatever is written on the first one. If there are different underlying pdfs that are appended later then it works ok.

Comment: So my question for you is -- Is there a way I can somehow modify the underlying PDF by changing some 'metadata' or something? Then I can just make 50 duplicates of the underlying PDF that are all "slightly different" and then I can read them in and write to them and google chrome will think they are different.